# Format PHP form $result = [msg]

Tags: php, formatting

How can I add html elements to this:

```
$return['msg'] = 'Thank you: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' email address: ' . $_POST['email']  . 'Your Message: ' . $_POST['message'] ;
```

to make it look nice. I've tried just putting like a `<br/>` in that broke it, then I tried putting a `'<br/>'` but that doesnt work either - as the formatting is so that it can display nicely on successful form submission - I'm getting the results just not the formatting.

The form is being submitted by AJAX and the results displayed by json_encode.

Comment: How are you passing the message?  How are you printing it?

Comment: hi there, its being sent through AJAX and php>

if (!$return['error'])
 $return['msg'] = 'Thank you: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' email address: ' . $_POST['email']  . 'Your Message: ' . $_POST['message'] ;

echo json_encode($return);

Answer (score 1):

Use the br element when you want a line break:

```
$return['msg'] = 'Thank you: ' . $_POST['name'] . '<br />email address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '<br />Your Message: ' . $_POST['message'] ;
```

Or you could put them into paragraphs:

```
$return['msg'] = '<p>Thank you: ' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>';
$return['msg'] .= '<p>email address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>';
$return['msg'] .= '<p>Your Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>';
```

Comment: Ah yeah! thats what I'm talkin about - super and many thanks!

Comment: Cool, no probs, any time. :-)

Comment: eish... its a good thing about this 8 min wait to accept answer thing... I mean the code looks great like it will do what I need... but when I look at the result its the same I just get the <p> tags in the soup

Comment: ah... yes its not working. It might be because of this>
echo json_encode($return);
but I'm not sure. I mean how can I break it up and add elements

Comment: You don't need to json_encode if you're just sending HTML. Hope I'm right about that, give it a go...

Comment: Thanks Matt, no I have it so that when the user submits the form they see the data/ whatever they've put in the inputs on submit. As far as I can tell I need to do this through AJAX and hence the json - but I'm really new at this and I'm guessing but aftfer spending the weekend trying to get it done.. I really just need a result

Comment: Personally I would just echo $return['msg']; as plain HTML and not precess the message as JSON on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

```
$return['msg'] = "Thank you: {$_POST['name']}<br />email address: {$_POST['email']}<br />Your Message: {$_POST['message']}";
```

Note the use of `{}` around the variables. They let you embed "complex" variables within a double-quoted string (though they're not strictly necessary in this case), and save you having to do the repeated string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the html formatting inside the single quotes.  For example...

```
$return['msg'] = 'Thank you: ' . $_POST['name'] .   '<br />email address: ' . $_POST['email']  . '<br />Your Message:<br />' . $_POST['message'] ;
```

Comment: Yeah same as above. I think I should have said about the > echo json_encode($return); of it going through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

In php :

**Constant** values (static words, html...) have to have single `'` or double `"` quotes around them. **Variables** on the other hand , while in a string of other variables or constants, have to have a `.` to seperate them.

So you could have something like this :

```
$message = '<div id="message">'; 
$message .= '<h2>Thank you: ' . $_POST['name'] . '</h2>'; 
$message .= 'Email address: ' . $_POST['email'] . "<br />"; //this br is the same
$message .= 'Your Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '<br />'; //as this br.
$message .= '</div>'; 

$return['msg'] = $message;
```

**Note :** `.=` concatenates the new string to old one.
 Quotes surounded by the same type of quotes have to be escaped `" <div id=\"escaped\"> "` with a backslash.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Dude thank you for this, its a great explanation for how it works and I'll definately use this knowledge going forward. But for now its not working it also displays out with all the <tags>... I think it has to do with json_encode

Comment: Yeah json adds backslashes, so you've probably got things like `<\/h2>` Try this : `echo str_replace('\\/','/',$return['msg']);` or just before you print/echo the message out.